# Различие в парсинге ссылок браузером и сервером

Tags: дефект, markdown

Наткнулся на ссылку вида `httpS://google.com`

В тексте вопроса вы её сейчас не видите, вот тут →

Но если открыть правку этого вопроса и посмотреть там в предпросмотр, то ссылка отлично отображается

Comment: (наверно это на метамету, но я не англичанин)

Comment: Прикольный хак)

Comment: забавно, но в предпросмотре она вполне себе показывается

Comment: @Grundy так об этом и репорт.

Comment: Если Вы не против, могу отрапортовать на MSE по этому багу.

Comment: @alexolut не против, я всё равно не умею)

Comment: [Готово](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314823/339911).

Comment: Ох, а я помню такое часто было но совершенно не в протоколе ссылок.. Тут в другом дело.